# Überleben vs. Überstehen

Tags: grammar, verb-choice

> Vermutlich steht so eine Behandlung auch bei mir an. ich habe große Angst davor zumal ich keine Betäubungsmittel bekommen kann (Allergie). meine Frage ist das Ganze auch ohne Lokalanästhetika zu `überstehen`?

Kann man das Verb "überstehen" mit "überleben"  im Kontext wechseln?

Comment: What research have you done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Du kannst die beiden Wörter `überstehen` und `überleben` austauschen, dann erhältst du aber eine leicht andere Bedeutung.

- `überleben`: Die Möglichkeit, zu sterben, ist tatsächlich gegeben.
- `überstehen`: Eigentlich besteht zwar nicht die Möglichkeit, zu sterben, sondern anderer Übel. Uneigentlich ist diese Aussicht aber meistens überzogen und man meint lediglich `ohne große Schmerzen durchzumachen`.

Comment: Ich finde nicht, dass man die Wörter austauschen kann (solange nicht die Möglichkeit besteht, dass man vor Schmerzen stirbt). *Überstehen* kann beispielsweise heißen: Bis zum Ende aushalten. *Überleben* sagt man zwar umgangssprachlich (*Ich dachte, ich überlebe die Schmerzen nicht*), aber im oben genannten Zusammenhang wäre die vermutliche Antwort von geschultem medizinischen Personal (beispielsweise bei einer Zahnbehandlung): "Überleben werden Sie es, aber schön wird es nicht...".

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Da du selber für beide Verben zumindest halbwegs sinnvolle Bedeutungen angegeben hast, kann man sie -- mit Bedeutungsänderung -- austauschen.

Comment: Hm, mit DER Argumentation kann man ja in jedem Satz jedes Wort durch ein anderes ersetzen - man bekommt ja einfach nur eine andere Bedeutung...

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Nicht unbedingt, weil nicht alle Wörter zusammen passen.

Comment: *Ehrlich*!? Potzblitz, das hätte ich ja nicht gedacht. Und ich war schon kurz davor, dem OP vorzuschlagen, er soll doch lieber fragen, ob er das alles auch ohne Narkose Blutwurst!

Answer (score 2):

Nein.

- überstehen: etwas hinter sich bringen, das sehr schwer oder schmerzhaft ist, siehe auch "durchstehen". Hier: Kann man die Operation überstehen, obwohl sie ohne Betäubung sehr schmerzhaft ist?
- überleben: der Tod bei der Operation ist sehr wahrscheinlich oder sogar sicher. Anderes Beispiel: "Den Auto-Unfall kann man ohne Gurt nicht überleben"